# I can't create another instance of my class but with different properties

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

When I select a variation and add a food item to the cart https://ibb.co/483gmHf which is the `userOrders` list it looks like this https://ibb.co/FsgLm19 which is good. But when I go back and change the variation of the food item https://ibb.co/rfddZdv and add to cart, it changes all previous variations of the orders and makes it look like this https://ibb.co/g3GYqLJ

When its supposed to look like this https://ibb.co/1rLMv49

I'm supposed to create a new food tile with 1 as the quantity but with a different variation. But instead I duplicate the previous order and change all variations for the food items. How do I do this https://ibb.co/g3GYqLJ properly?

```
class Food {
  String imgUrl;
  String desc;
  String name;
  String waitTime;
  num score;
  int price;
  int pq;
  int quantity;
  bool favourited;
  List<Variation> variations;
  Variation? selectedVar;
  String about;
  bool highlight;
  Food(this.imgUrl, this.desc, this.name, this.pq, this.waitTime, this.score,
      this.price, this.quantity, this.variations, this.about, this.favourited,
      {this.highlight = false});

  int pqProduct(Food food) {
    pq = food.quantity * food.price;
    return pq;
  }
}
```

Variation

```
class Variation {
  String title;
  String imgURL;
  bool selected = false;
  Variation(this.imgURL, this.title);
}
```

Instance of Food in question

```
Food(
        'assets/images/sha-modified.png',
        'Most Recommended',
        'Shawarma',
        0,
        '15 min',
        4.5,
        1500,
        0,
        [
          Variation('assets/images/cabbb-modified.png', 'Chicken'),
          Variation('assets/images/chicken-modified.png', 'Beef'),
          Variation('assets/images/flatbread-modified.png', 'Mexican'),
          Variation('assets/images/sauce-modified.png', 'Suya'),
        ],
        'A sandwich of sliced lamb or chicken, vegetables, and often tahini wrapped in pita bread',
        highlight: true,
        false,
      ),
```

FoodQuantity

```
class FoodQuantity extends StatefulWidget {
  final Food food;
  FoodQuantity(this.food);

  @override
  State<FoodQuantity> createState() => _FoodQuantityState();
}

class _FoodQuantityState extends State<FoodQuantity> {
  final int amount = 0;
  bool showSignInDialog = false;

  String getCurrency() {
    var format = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(name: 'NGN');
    return format.currencySymbol;
  }

  Future<int> counter() async {
    final int result = await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      int result = context.read<FoodCount>().display(widget.food);
      return result;
    });
    return result;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.maxFinite,
      height: 40,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: const Alignment(-1, 0), //0.3
            child: Container(
              width: 120,
              height: double.maxFinite,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(width: 15), //Spacing
                  Text(
                    getCurrency(),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    widget.food.price.toString(),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 24,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: const Alignment(1, 0), //0.3
            child: Container(
              height: double.maxFinite,
              width: 120,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xff453658),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      if (context.read<Counter>().count != 0) {
                        context.read<FoodCount>().decrement(widget.food);
                        setState(() {});
                      } else {
                        errorDialog(
                          context,
                          'ERROR',
                          "You can't buy -1 ${widget.food.name}s",
                        );
                      }
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      '-',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 30,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white38),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      context
                          .watch<FoodCount>()
                          .display(widget.food)
                          .toString(),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      if (widget.food.selectedVar == null) {
                        errorDialog(
                          context,
                          'ERROR',
                          'Please select a variation',
                        );
                      } else {
                        if (selectedVars.contains(widget.food.selectedVar)) {
                          if (userOrders.contains(widget.food)) {
                            context.read<FoodCount>().increment(widget.food);
                            context.read<Counter>().update();
                          } else {
                            userOrders.add(widget.food);
                            context.read<Counter>().update();
                            setState(() {});
                          }
                        } else {
                          selectedVars.add(widget.food.selectedVar);
                          userOrders.add(widget.food);
                          context.read<FoodCount>().increment(widget.food);
                          context.read<Counter>().update();
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      '+',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white38,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

FoodCount provider

```
class FoodCount with ChangeNotifier {
  void increment(Food food) {
    food.quantity++;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void decrement(Food food) {
    food.quantity--;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int display(Food food) {
    int count = food.quantity;
    return count;
  }

  void reset(Food food) {
    food.quantity = 0;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void update() {
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

CheckoutView

```
class ListScrollView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<ListScrollView> createState() => _ListScrollViewState();
}

class _ListScrollViewState extends State<ListScrollView> {
  Widget _buildIconText(IconData icon, Color color, String text) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Icon(
          icon,
          color: color,
          size: 14,
        ),
        Text(
          text,
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return userOrders.isNotEmpty
        ? Expanded(
            child: ListView.separated(
              itemCount: userOrders.length,
              itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                return Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                  height: 160,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Stack(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            width: 130,
                            height: 130,
                            child: Image.asset(userOrders[index].imgUrl,
                                fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            width: 60,
                            height: 60,
                            child: Image.asset(
                              userOrders[index].selectedVar!.imgURL,
                              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 20,
                            left: 10,
                            right: 10,
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                                    child: Text(
                                      userOrders[index].name,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  IconButton(
                                    icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      context
                                          .read<FoodCount>()
                                          .reset(userOrders[index]);
                                      userOrders.remove(userOrders[index]);
                                      context.read<TotalPrice>().update();
                                      context.read<FavFood>().peeQee();
                                      context.read<Counter>().update();
                                      context.read<FavFood>().update();
                                      setState(() {});
                                    },
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                              Text(
                                userOrders[index].selectedVar!.title,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                              ),
                              _buildIconText(
                                Icons.access_time_outlined,
                                Colors.blue,
                                userOrders[index].waitTime,
                              ),
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    getCurrency(),
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    '${userOrders[index].price}',
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        context
                                            .read<FoodCount>()
                                            .decrement(userOrders[index]);
                                        context.read<FavFood>().peeQee();
                                        context.read<Counter>().update();
                                        context.read<FavFood>().update(); //
                                        if (context
                                                .read<FoodCount>()
                                                .display(userOrders[index]) ==
                                            0) {
                                          userOrders.remove(userOrders[index]);
                                        }
                                        setState(() {});
                                      },
                                      child: const Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                                        child: Text(
                                          '-',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 30,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                        color: Color(0xff453658),
                                      ),
                                      child: Text(
                                        context
                                            .watch<FoodCount>()
                                            .display(userOrders[index])
                                            .toString(),
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          color: Colors.white70,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        context
                                            .read<FoodCount>()
                                            .increment(userOrders[index]);
                                        context.read<FavFood>().update();
                                        context.read<Counter>().update();
                                        context.read<FavFood>().peeQee();
                                        setState(() {});
                                      },
                                      child: const Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                                        child: Text(
                                          '+',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 30,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }),
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                  const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
            ),
          )
        : Column(
            children: const [
              Text('No items in basket'),
            ],
          );
  }
}
```

Counter provider

```
class Counter with ChangeNotifier {
  int _count = userOrders.fold(
      0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element.quantity);

  int get count => _count;

  void reset() {
    _count = 0;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int update() {
    _count = userOrders.fold(
        0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element.quantity);
    notifyListeners();
    return _count;
  }
}

List<Variation?> selectedVars = [];

List<Food> userOrders = [];
```

Comment: My guess would be that the two items are under the same object/class.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you call the Quantity Widget, but it might be the case it's not being rebuilt when a new flavor is selected. So every time you add a different flavor from the same item to userOrders, you are adding the same Food Object.

Also keep in mind that this expression `if (userOrders.contains(widget.food))` should not work as you expect. Even if two objects Food have all the same values, they are not considered the same, (unless they are in fact the same). You can change this behavior using "Equatable" (recommended) or "Freezed" (a bit more elaborated).

Maybe a better approach to have a food object (without quantity and selectedFlav) and a separate object ItemOrdered with only the foodId, quantity and flavor.

In any case, the following change in your Checkout might show the proper Flavor in your current code:

Instead of: `userOrders[index].selectedVar!.title,`

Try:  `context.read<Counter>().selectedVars[index]!.title`